# Meteor: how to automatically populate field with length of array stored in other field in a collection?

Tags: meteor, simple-schema, meteor-collection-hooks

I have a collection defined with SimpleSchema/Collection2 like this:

```
Schema.Stuff = new SimpleSchema({
    pieces: {
        type: [Boolean],
    },
    num_pieces: {
        type: Number,
    },
```

**How can I get `num_pieces` to automatically be populated with the length of the `pieces` array whenever there is a change?**

I am open to using SimpleSchema's `autoValue` or `matb33:collection-hooks`.  `pieces` could potentially be changed with quite a few operators, such as `$push`, `$pull`, `$set`, and probably more that Mongo has to offer, and I had no idea how to cope with these possibilities.  Ideally one would just look at the value of `pieces` after the update, but how can you do that and make a change without going into a bit of an infinite loop on the collection-hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you'd do a collection hook 'after update' that prevents the infinite loop:

```
Stuff.after.update(function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options) {
  if( (!this.previous.pieces && doc.pieces) || (this.previous.pieces.length !== doc.pieces.length ) {
    // Two cases to be in here:
    // 1. We didn't have pieces before, but we do now.
    // 2. We had pieces previous and now, but the values are different.
    Stuff.update({ _id: doc._id }, { $set: { num_pieces: doc.pieces.length } });
  }
});
```

Note that `this.previous` gives you access to the previous document, and `doc` is the current document.  This should give you enough to finish the rest of the cases.

Comment: Just a missing close bracket on the if, otherwise works a charm - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it right in the schema

```
Schema.Stuff = new SimpleSchema({
  pieces: {
    type: [Boolean],
  },
  num_pieces: {
    type: Number,
    autoValue() {
      const pieces = this.field('pieces');
      if (pieces.isSet) {
        return pieces.value.length
      } else {
        this.unset();
      }
    }    
  },
});
```

Comment: someone posted the same answer earlier and have now deleted it. I tried this, and it doesn't work because `pieces.value` refers to the incoming modifier e.g. `true` rather than the resultant field value e.g. `[false,true,true]`